# App crash, How to resolve?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem when I run my app and select an item from my spinner instead of opening a new class like it is supposed to the app crashes, I was wondering if anyone could help me with why this is happening.  I am not sure what part of the code to include, so I will include the Logcat and if you request any code I will edit this post.

Thanks.

Logcat:

```
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.famouspeople/com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery.initialize(SeanConnery.java:44)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery.onCreate(SeanConnery.java:28)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The important line is: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery.initialize(SeanConnery.java:44)

Comment: Check your `onCreate()` method of  `SeanConnery` Line number:28.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I believe I had the wrong view in setContentView.

Comment: I think you should check out SeanConnery.java, line 44.

Comment: If you dubbleclick at the "03-09 15:36:53.814: E/AndroidRuntime(13429):    at com.example.famouspeople.SeanConnery.initialize(SeanConnery.java:44)" line you see where your nullpointerexception comes from. If you hace any futher questions post the code!

Answer (score 2):

Normally when app crashes with the click on spinner, the problem lies with the adapter you are using to populate the spinner, check carefully the length of apapter you defined. Follow this code

```
 int num = SpinnerData.length;
    SpinnerData = new String[num];
Log.d("ArrayAdapter",""+ SpinnerData.length);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CurrentActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SpinnerData);
                    //spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

check carefully length ..I hope this help